# Why a form having foreign keys in giving field error in django on form submission

Tags: django

I am creating a feedback form. This form has three foreign keys.
My views.py is

```
def studentFeedBack(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        studentid_id = request.POST.get("studentid")
        studentid = Student.objects.get(id=studentid_id)

        courseid_id = request.POST.get("courseid")
        courseid = Course.objects.get(id=courseid_id)


        teacherid_id = request.POST.get("teacherid")
        teacherid = SchoolTeacher.objects.get(id=teacherid_id)

        description = request.POST.get("description")
        rating = request.POST.get("rating")
        
        studentFeedBackModel.objects.create(
            courseid=courseid,
            description=description, 
            studentid=studentid, 
            teacherid=teacherid, 
            rating=rating
        )

    return render(
            request,
            'forms/studentFeedBack.html',
            {
                
                'studentids':Student.objects.all(),
                'courseids':Course.objects.all(),
                'teacherids':SchoolTeacher.objects.all(),
                
            }
        )
```

and my model for feedback form is

```
class StudentFeedBack(models.Model):
    feedbackid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    courseid = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    submitdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    teacherid = models.ForeignKey('SchoolTeacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    studentid = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = [('Good','Good'),('Average','Average'),('Bad','Bad')]
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=option, default='none')
```

The above model has foreign key from models

```
class Course(models.Model):
    courseid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    coursedescription = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    coursename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    videolink = models.FileField(default='default_link')
    # roleid = models.ForeignKey(RoleName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    createddate = models.DateTimeField()
    imagelink = models.URLField(default='default_link')
    duration = models.DateTimeField()
    longdes = models.TextField()
    coursetype = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # classid = models.ForeignKey(TblClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.BinaryField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.coursename


    class Meta:
        db_table = "courseids"      


class SchoolTeacher(models.Model):
    teacherid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    # classid = models.ForeignKey(TblClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # schoolid = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    passowrd = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')
    regno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    joiningdate = models.DateTimeField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name


    class Meta:
        db_table = "teacherids"    


class Student(models.Model):
    studentid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    regno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    registrationdate = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # classid = models.ForeignKey(TblClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # schoolid = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    imagepath = models.ImageField(max_length=100, default='default.jpg')
    sectionid = models.IntegerField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name   


    class Meta:
        db_table = "studentids"
```

The html form for the feedback form is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/studentFeedBack/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
          
          <label for="studentid">Student Id</label>
          <select name="studentid" required>
            {% for studentid in studentids  %}
              <option value="{{studentid.id}}">{{studentid.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
         </select><br><br>

          <label for="courseid">Course Id</label>
          <select name="courseid" required>
            {% for courseid in courseids  %}
              <option value="{{courseid.id}}">{{courseid.coursename}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
         </select><br><br>

          <label for="teacherid">Teacher Id</label>
          <select name="teacherid" required>
            {% for teacherid in teacherids  %}
              <option value="{{teacherid.id}}">{{teacherid.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
         </select><br><br>


          <label for="description" >Feedback</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description"></textarea><br><br>

          <label for="rating">Rating</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Good" name="rating" value="Good">
          <label for="Good">Good</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Average" name="rating" value="Average">
          <label for="Average">Average</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Bad" name="rating" value="Bad">
          <label for="Bad">Bad</label><br><br>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </form>
        

</body>
</html>
```

Everything is working fine in command prompt and browser as soon as the form is submitted it is giving the following error

FieldError at /studentFeedBack/
Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: address, contactno, email, imagepath, name, password, registrationdate, regno, sectionid, studentfeedback, studentid

I tried adding the data manually in admin panel and its working completely okay

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that your models have studentid/courseid/teacherid as primary keys. Which means that your models no longer have an `id` field.

You'll will see the same problem if you inspect your html, as the values will be empty. You could replace your `id` with `pk` (which is always usable) or the correct primary key field.

Another note, check out Django ModelForms, which help you with the validation of the data. As now you'll get DoesNotExists errors (or even ValueErrors) if someone hijacks your form and posts in random data.